# designing better and crisp server.js (the file which is called to start node application 'e.g. node server.js')

Tags: javascript, web-development, node.js

While creating server.js file we need to provide routes information as

```
var Login = require('./routes/login.js');
app.use('/login', Login);
```

Now, suppose the node project is a REST services project. so this type of entries could extend to lots of lines , meaning for every route we need to provide the above given 2 lines of code in server.js.
 
Similarly, if there is lots of 'require' statements which are needed to start the server and if there is some code related to middle ware , routing mechanism, analytics mechanism etc. etc.

How would it, then, be possible to keep the server.js file crisp(keeping it short and simple) and easy to understand?

How and what design pattern I should follow to make server.js beautiful?

Comment: You should search (both google and stackoverflow) for 'dynamic routing'.

Comment: Beauty is subjective.

Comment: This seems like an on-topic (if basic) question for SE.  Why all the down votes?

Comment: @Orangesandlemons. Ok, i will search about it . but still I would like to discuss about this question as I am more interested in keeping the server js file as much modularized and as it  can be . like keeping middle ware to one js , routing to another js , security token development to another js file and just referencing all of them to server js or connecting everything in app object kind of . I hope you understand my question .

Comment: @GauravShukla I don't know how proficient you are with node, but if you want to split up code you can (where it makes sense to do so) make your own files, require the relevant modules within them, and then use module.exports to require that in server.js. But first you need to make sure you have a clear idea of what the code is doing.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons I am already doing it . I am asking one thing , how much small ,self-explanatory , and simple a server.js could be made which is handling nearly 100 of routes(think about a production environment of bigdata and analytics application.)

Comment: @routing can be done dynamically, as stated. Modularity depends on how you design the code, as is making the app self-explanatory (although good documentation practises, including clear code commenting is also important)